# using crypt value to retrieve user password

Tags: php, hash

I use crypt to hash user password and store into my db the hashed password when a user sign up in my application.
Then when the user sign in in my application I retrieve the crypted password from my db and compare the new hashed password with the initial hashed password.
My issue is I never get same value.
I read to use salt with the initial password to improve security.
My code is as follow :

```
    $sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE mail =:mail";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array(':mail'=>$mail));
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (count($result) == 1){
       $interne = $result[0]['password'];
       $crypt = crypt($pass, $interne);
       if($interne === $crypt){
        echo "loggedin";
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use varchar to store the hash, because char might be padded with whitespace.

This is for example the case for [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html):

> When CHAR values are stored, they are right-padded with spaces to the specified length.

Answer (score -1):

You probably do not allow nuff place for the full hash in the database. Did you set varchar 40 or somethinng like this? If yes allow 255 varchar and it should work

Comment: Yes I did password=char(255)